# R code help- script does not work, but console works

Tags: r

Hi I am trying to run a r script

```
loadData <- function()
{
  library(XLConnect)
  excel0157 <- loadWorkbook("C:\\Users\\\\Documents\\R\\data\\0157\\0157.xlsx")
  sheet_names <- getSheets(excel0157)
  c0157 <- readWorksheetFromFile("C:\\Users\\\\Documents\\R\\data\\0157\\0157.xlsx",sheet = sheet_names[1],region = "B4:B27", header = FALSE)
  for (i in 1:79) {
  c0157[i] <-readWorksheetFromFile("C:\\Users\\\\Documents\\R\\data\\0157\\0157.xlsx",sheet = sheet_names[i],region = "B4:B27", header = FALSE)
  }
  c0157ts1 <- as.numeric(c(t(c0157)))
}
```

However, c0157ts1 does not create. If I run the `c0157ts1 <- as.numeric(c(t(c0157)))` in the console, c0157ts1 is created.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: `c0157ts1 <- loadData()`

Comment: Thanks. It works now. Can you explain the situation?

Comment: When you assign a variable in a function it is not created in the global environment.

Comment: It is little bit weird to me. I can access c0157, but not c0157ts.

Comment: A function in R should always return any values you want to use later. If you don't return the value from the function, it disappears. A function should not create variables outside it's own scope. This is a basic principle of functional programming languages.